# How to increase line heigh in an EditText for new text paragraph

Tags: android

I have an EditText and I would like to have a bigger space between lines but **only when the user creates a new line** by pressing return. 
I don't want the space to be bigger when the text goes back by itself because the line is too long.

I tryed to use `lineSpacingExtra` but unfortunately it change the line height in both cases.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use something like this myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));

Comment: @EliasFazel I think I can't do that in an EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it using spans.
Every time I detect an inserted "\n" (using a TextWatcher) I wrap my new line with a TopPaddedSpan.

```
class TopPaddedSpan implements LineHeightSpan {

    private boolean initialised = false;
    private int originalAscent;
    private int increasedAscent;

    @Override
    public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int spanstartv, int v, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        if (!initialised) {
            originalAscent = fm.ascent;
            increasedAscent = Math.round(fm.ascent * 1.6f);
            initialised = true;
        }
        if (spanstartv == v) { // First drawn line
            fm.ascent = increasedAscent;
        } else { // Any other lines
            fm.ascent = originalAscent;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a TextWatcher and handle your logic from the provided callbacks.

Make your activity / fragment implement TextWatcher.

Implement the callbacks.

Hold a boolean variable in your activity / fragment to indicate whether the line spacing is in a 'large' state.

```
private boolean largeLines = false;
private EditText inputText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    inputText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // Do nothing
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // Check if the text contains a new line character
    if (s.toString().contains("\n")) {

        // If we haven't already, increase the line spacing by 1.2x
        if (!largerLines) {
            inputText.setLineSpacing(0, 1.2f);
            largerLines = true;
        }
    }
    // If there is no new line character & the line spacing is
    // large, make it smaller again by 0.8x
    else if (largerLines) {
        inputText.setLineSpacing(0, 0.8f);
        largerLines = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how it would work. This will change the line spacing of the entire editText when you call setLineSpacing()

Comment: When the user is typing normally, the line spacing will be small. Then, they press enter and a newline character is read. This will make "a bigger space between lines but only when the user creates a new line by pressing return". If they then delete this new line character, the line spacing will return to default